# Java program involving arrays displays random numbers when it runs

Tags: java, arrays, methods

For my Java class, I have this assignment:

> Write a program that generates 100 random integers in the range 0 to 25, and stores them in an array. Then, the program should call a class method that sorts the odd numbers into an array and returns the array. The program should then call another method that sorts the even numbers into a separate array and returns the array. Both arrays should then be displayed.

This is my code:

```
public class XandY
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] randomNums = new int [100];
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) { 
            randomNums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 26); 
            int[] oddNums = sortOdd(randomNums);
            System.out.println("The odd numbers are "); 
            for (int n = 0; n<=oddNums.length; n++) { 
            System.out.print(n); 
            } 
            int[] evenNums = sortEven(randomNums);
            System.out.println("The even numbers are ");
            for (int o = 0; o<=evenNums.length; o++) { 
            System.out.print(o); 
            } 
        }
    }

    public static int[] sortOdd(int[] randomNums)
    {
        int numOdds = 0;
        for (int x : randomNums){
            if(x % 2 == 1){
            ++numOdds;
            }
        }
        int[] oddNums = new int[numOdds]; 
        int z = 0;
        for (int n : randomNums){
            if(n % 2 == 1){
                oddNums[z] = n;
                z++;
            }
        }
        return oddNums;


    } 
    public static int[] sortEven(int[] randomNums)
    {
        int numEvens = 0;
        for (int x : randomNums){
            if(x % 2 == 0){
            ++numEvens;
            }
        }
        int[] evenNums = new int[numEvens];
        int z = 0;
        for (int n : randomNums){
            if(n % 2 == 0){
                evenNums[z] = n;
                z++;
            }
        }
        return evenNums;

    }



}
```

When it runs, it displays a bunch of random numbers. Could anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pretty sure you're just printing the increments..shouldn't you be printing System.out.print(oddNums[n]);  and not System.out.print(n);

Comment: You probably wanted `for (int n : oddNums) {` instead `for (int n = 0; n <= oddNums.length; n++) {` (which also should not have `<=` but `<`). Same about even numbers.

Comment: Even when changing that and System.out.print(n); to System.out.print(oddNums[n]); , I still received "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
 at XandY.main(XandY.java:11)" I am using Eclipse, if that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think this question is basically trying to use SO to debug your code. I think that you should: a) actively isolate your code to the smallest possible segment in which the problem occurs, b) provide a list of things you have tried changing and what the effect has been. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188210/should-faq-discourage-questions-that-are-an-attempt-to-use-so-as-a-free-debuggin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's fine except your main method.

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
    int [] randomNums = new int [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) { 
        randomNums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 26); 
    }
        int[] oddNums = sortOdd(randomNums);
        System.out.println("The odd numbers are "); 
        for (int n = 0; n<oddNums.length; n++) { 
        System.out.print(oddNums[n] + "  " ); 

    }
        int[] evenNums = sortEven(randomNums);
        System.out.println("The even numbers are ");
        for (int o = 0; o<evenNums.length; o++) { 
        System.out.print(evenNums[o] + "  "); 
        } 
}
```